# Правильность разметки HTML5 + Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, разметка, семантика

Прошу помощи, подскажите является ли мой пример разметки правильным, облазил кучу сайтов, но внятного ответа так и не получил, везде каждый пишет по разному... Хотелось бы узнать более правильный вариант.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      Header
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <article>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <section>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">Content 1</div>
                <div class="col-md-8">Content 2</div>
              </div>
            </section>

            <section>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">Content 1</div>
                <div class="col-md-8">Content 2</div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>

          <aside>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <section>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    Sidebar block 1
                  </div>
                </section>

                <section>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    Sidebar block 2
                  </div>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      Footer
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```